# php script validation error

Tags: php, w3c-validation

I'm having problem with using php script in xhtml file
When checking validation from W3C, it keep showing this annoying message :

```
character "<" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data
```

here is my code

```
    <tr>
        <td scope="row"><?php echo $prod_id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $prod_name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $prod_date; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $prod_price; ?></td>
        <td> 
            <form action="./prod_edit.php" method="get" >
                <input type="hidden" name="query_access" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $prod_id; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="<?php echo $prod_name; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="product_date" value="<?php echo $prod_date; ?>" />   
                <input type="hidden" name="product_price" value="<?php echo $prod_price; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" name="edit_button" value="Edit"  />
            </form>
        </td>
        <td> 
            <form action="./prod_delete.php" method="get">
                <input type="hidden" name="query_access" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $prod_id; ?>" />                  
                <input type="hidden" name="product_name" value="<?php echo $prod_name; ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="product_date" value="<?php echo $prod_date; ?>" />   
                <input type="hidden" name="product_price" value="<?php echo $prod_price; ?>" />
                <input type="submit" name="delete_button" value="Delete"  />
            </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you post the final html generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're validating the wrong code. Your final code will not have the php unexecuted inside. So as far as I know, replacing the php part with a sample echo of `$prod_id` should give you the wanted results.

You want to validate **what the browser gets**, not what the server does.

Comment: pasting the php code into a validator.  I wouldn't have thought he'd do that.

Comment: But my code works well, check page validation is my final step.

Comment: HTML validators can't understand php. You need to pass the page to a validator through a web browser so that the server processes all of the PHP code.

Comment: @aynber you're right, I validated the page from dreamweaver, so it displayed the warning message. I've just checked it from website, It show OK now